# Why does the Ito Integral send Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences?

Tags: analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I came across this remark in some lecture notes, and don't have a good intuition or proof for why this is true. Is it because the sequence of Brownian increments can be bounded by a sequence of deterministic constants almost surely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this was a reasonable question so I'm not going to delete it, but I now see why this is true. Just rewrite the integral as the Ito isometry, and the result should follow trivially.